# How to renew self-signed CA certificate openldap

Tags: openldap

On year ago we setup an openldap system based on the following Ubuntu tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html

Now the CA certificate is expired.

TLS is not working anymore .

Any ideas how to renew the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Ok we found the solution ourselves. For those who are interested this is what we did:

Apparently we forgot to set an expiration days value and it defaulted to 365 days. That is why it expired.

The openldap server only uses the paths of the CA certificate cacert.pem,
the private server key (hostname.slapd.pem) and the server certificate (signed with the cacert.pem).
This means we didn't have to change the openldap configuration.

We just needed to recreate / replace the CA certificate.
For convenience reasons we kept the private certificate authority key and the private server key.

1. We recreated the CA certificate using the existing private CA key and made sure the expiration days value was more than one year. We had used a template file before and just added the expiration days line.
2. We recreated the server certificate using the existing server private key and signed with the newly created CA certificate from step 1.
3. We restarted our slapd service

If you are using a replication slave openldap server, do not forget to sign a new slave server certificate with the new CA certificate and restart the slapd service. Replication should be working then.

All is fixed now.

Comment: That's why my self-signed local-use certificates have 10-year validity. :)